# Linkedin Integration with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am working on Meteor trying to implement linkedin oauth. I have a button, when user clicks it, a window appears asking the user to allow access, when the user allows, the profile info of the user has to be displayed.

My Approach.

When button is clicked, I am injecting this

```
"window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000%2F_oauth%2Flinkedin%3Fclose&scope=&state=XXXXX', 'newwindow', 'width=400, height=250');"
```

which opens a new window that asks access permission. And when user allows access by giving username and password, the window goes off instantly. I know that linkedin directs it to our app giving authorization code and state in the url. And I need to use this authorization code to get the access token. But I am not being able to catch this authorization code.

Please let me know how can I achieve this functionality and if my approach is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reply for all those who voted down the question. I was finally able to do it.

```
Session.set('authCode',null);
Session.set('profile',null);
Template.home.events({
    'click .viewLinkedinProfileButton' :function(event, template){
        var redirect_uri = encodeURIComponent(Meteor.absoluteUrl('userAuthComplete'));
        var client_id='XXXXXXX';
        var state = 'myRandomString';
        var scope = ['r_basicprofile'];
        var url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id="+client_id+"&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+"&state="+state+"&scope=r_basicprofile";

        showPopup(url,function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log("Cancelled "+err);
            }
            else{
                Meteor.call('getAccessToken',Session.get('authCode'),function(err,res){
                    if(res){
                        console.log(res);
                        Session.set('profile',res);
                    }
                });
                Session.set('authCode',null);
            }
        })
    }
});

function showPopup(url, callback, dimensions) {
    // default dimensions that worked well for facebook and google
    var popup = openCenteredPopup(
        url,
        (dimensions && dimensions.width) || 650,
        (dimensions && dimensions.height) || 331
    );

    var checkPopupOpen = setInterval(function() {
        try {
            var popupClosed = popup.closed || popup.closed === undefined;
        } catch (e) {
            return;
        }

        if (popupClosed) {
            var url = popup.document.URL;
            if(url.toLowerCase().indexOf('code') !== -1){
                var array1 = url.split('code=');
                var array2 =array1[1].split('&');
                Session.set('authCode',array2[0]);
                clearInterval(checkPopupOpen);
                callback();
            }
            else{
                clearInterval(checkPopupOpen);
            }
        }
    }, 50);
}

function openCenteredPopup(url, width, height) {
    var screenX = typeof window.screenX !== 'undefined'
        ? window.screenX : window.screenLeft;
    var screenY = typeof window.screenY !== 'undefined'
        ? window.screenY : window.screenTop;
    var outerWidth = typeof window.outerWidth !== 'undefined'
        ? window.outerWidth : document.body.clientWidth;
    var outerHeight = typeof window.outerHeight !== 'undefined'
        ? window.outerHeight : (document.body.clientHeight - 22);
    var left = screenX + (outerWidth - width) / 2;
    var top = screenY + (outerHeight - height) / 2;
    var features = ('width=' + width + ',height=' + height +
    ',left=' + left + ',top=' + top + ',scrollbars=yes');

    var newwindow = window.open(url, 'Login', features);
    if (newwindow.focus)
        newwindow.focus();
    return newwindow;
}


Template.home.helpers({
   profile:function(){
       return Session.get('profile');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the accounts-linkedin package to do this: https://atmospherejs.com/pauli/accounts-linkedin

You can add it with:

`meteor add accounts-linkedin`

Alternatively, look at the source code for that package if you really want to know how it's done.

Comment: Thanks for the -1. Lol. Great to come on here and answer your question to get down voted. It's worked for me in the past. And has 8.3k downloads so maybe the problem is with you

Comment: I did not vote u down, u fool. I have just created my SO account and have only 2 reputations, so cant vote any question down.

Comment: Haha. My bad. Two people voted you down! Not me though. Sincerest apologies

Comment: no worries... May be they didnt understand the question, f!tards!